# Rolling 12 month with Multiple columns (or dimension) in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Let suppose i have these fields in my table Year, Month, Customer,Market,Product,Production Place, Category and Sales(decimal). Now I want an addition column Rolling 12 Sales which calculates sum of sales for current month + past 11 month.

rolling 12 sales (feb 2014)= sales (march 2013)+ sales (april 2013)+..........+sale (Feb 2014)

We have already achieved it using Co-related Sub query with AND condition for all the dimension, but that doesn't provides right out put!

Co-related sub=query works when i have only 4 colum like year, month , customer and sales

Please help!

Regards
Sushant

Comment: How is the output you get incorrect?  Too high? Too low?  Null?

Comment: Hi Ann, I have created the same query, the problem the values are low. We created two queries one with Year, Month,Category, Sales, Rolling12Sales and second one with Year, Month,Category, SubCategory, Sales, Rolling12Sales. We tested data from 2nd query in a pivot table to compare it to values in first query. It seems that suppose I have few subcategory which are there in current month and not there in previous month, the formula fails to take them into account while aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that if your table's columns are

```
 Year, Month, Customer,Market,Product,Production Place, Category and Sales(decimal)
```

... you want your Rolling 12 Sales column to be only the last 12 months' sales for that customer, market, product, production place, and category, rather than summarized to some higher level.

You don't say whether any of these columns can be Null, but I'm going to assume they can't, for simplicity.

I would expect this to work (given the conditions I mention above):

```
 Select    Year
       ,   Month
       ,   Customer
       ,   Market
       ,   Product
       ,   [Production Place]
       ,   Category
       ,   Sales
       ,   [Rolling 12 Month] = 
             (Select   SUM(t2.Sales)
              From     Table1  t2
              Where    t1.Customer = t2.Customer
                 and   t1.Market = t2.Market
                 and   t1.Product = t2.Product
                 and   T1.[Production Place] = t2.[Production Place]
                 and   t1.Category = t2.Category
                 and   (
                         (t2.Year = t1.Year and t2.Month <= t1.Month)
                     OR  (t2.Year = t1.Year - 1 and t2.Month > t1.Month)
                 )
              )
 From      Table1 t1
```

If any of those columns in the subquery's WHERE clause are nullable, change their format to this:

```
 Where ((t1.Market = t2.Market) or (t1.Market IS NULL and t2.Market IS NULL))
```

If this doesn't work, please explain what error message or incorrect data you get.  Thanks.

ETA:  You asked whether this could be made to work in a stored procedure.  I don't see why it couldn't.  You didn't say what the parameters of the stored procedure needed to be (Customer?  Current Year and Month?) so the version below has no parameters and returns data for all products and customers that had activity for the last twelve months.

```
 Create dbo.Procedure1()
 AS
 Begin
   declare  @CurrentMonth int
       ,    @CurrentYear int

   -- If you want to parameterize this, you could make @CurrentMonth and @CurrentYear parameters
   -- and skip this.
   set @currentMonth = DatePart(MM, GetDate())
   set @CurrentYear = DatePart(YYYY,GetDate())

   ;
   with SalesFor12Months
   as (
     select  Year
         ,   Month
         ,   Customer
         ,   Market
         ,   Product
         ,   [Production Place]
         ,   Category
         ,   Sales
     from    Table1 t1
     where   (@CurrentYear = T1.Year and @CurrentMonth >= t1.Month)
          OR (@CurrentYear - 1 = t1.Year and @CurrentMonth < t1.Month)
   )
   ,  SalesForCurrentMonth
   as  (
     select  *
     from    Table1
     where   Month = @CurrentMonth
       and   Year = @CurrentYear
   )
   ,  AllCustomers
   as (
     select  distinct 
             Customer
         ,   Market
         ,   Product
         ,   [Production Place]
         ,   Category
     from    SalesFor12Months
  )
    select Month = @CurrentMonth
      ,    Year = @CurrentYear
      ,    ac.Customer
      ,    ac.Market
      ,    ac.Product   
      ,    ac.[Production Place]
      ,    ac.Category
      ,    Sales = COALESCE(curSales.Sales,0)
      ,    [Rolling 12 Month] = COALESCE(
             (Select   SUM(t2.Sales)
              From     SalesFor12Months  t2
              Where    ac.Customer = t2.Customer
                 and   ac.Market = t2.Market
                 and   ac.Product = t2.Product
                 and   ac.[Production Place] = t2.[Production Place]
                 and   ac.Category = t2.Category
              )
           ,0)
      from  AllCustomers ac
          left join SalesForCurrentMonth curSales
              on  ac.Customer = curSales.Customer
              and ac.Market = curSales.Market
              and ac.Product = curSales.Product
              and ac.[Production Place] = curSales.[Production Place]
              and ac.Category = curSales.Category
End
```

Hope that helps.  I did that without having test data so I apologize if there are typos or other errors.

Comment: Hi Ann, I have created the same query, the problem the values are low.   We created two queries one with Year, Month,Category, Sales, Rolling12Sales and second one with Year, Month,Category, SubCategory, Sales, Rolling12Sales. We tested data from 2nd query in a pivot table to compare it to values in first query. It seems that suppose I have few subcategory which are there in current month and not there in previous month, the formula fails to take them into account while aggregation.

Comment: I see.  And you probably need to see YTD sales for customers who didn't buy this month, but bought in previous months, right?

Comment: From that perspective, i should get current and past 11 month sales for all the product he brought in that duration.

Comment: To be precise, i believe, there can be records for which all the AND condition in sub query is not met, hence we get low values!

Comment: Hi, Will it be possible to achieve it in SQL Server procedure?

Comment: @user3449314 I think so.  I will amend my answer.

Comment: @user3449314  I have amended my answer.  I hope this is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thanks Ann for the help! will cross check your solution and revert back!

Comment: Hi Ann, Sorry to be coming back after such a long time, the issue went on the back burners. But now i have to implement your recommendation but couldnt get the same output! We have a application called Qlikview it executes the following requirement with this pseudo code mentioned below:

Answer (score 0):

```
Join SELECT
    'PMD' as RecType,
     PMID as RecID,
    CustomerID,
    PMMonth as Month,
    PMYear as Year,
    Quantity as Rolling12Packs,
    Size * Quantity / 1000 AS Rolling12Litres,
    (PMDelSpl.Method) as Method,
    (PMDelSpl.Size) as Size,
    (PMDelSpl.Shape) as Shape,
    (PMDelSpl.System) as System,
    (PMDelSpl.Type) as Type,
    (PMDelSpl.Category) as Category,
    (PMDelSpl.SubCat) as SubCat,
    (PMDelSpl.Place) as Place,
    PMDelSpl.Group,
    PMDelSpl.Distribution,
convert( datetime, str( PMYear ) + '/' + STR( PMMonth ) + '/01' ) as Period,
L_ProductType AS LocalCategory,
L_ProductCategory AS LocalSubcategory
FROM PMDelSpl;

**For i=1 to 11**
Join SELECT
    'PMD' as RecType,
PMID as RecID,
CustomerID,
Quantity as Rolling12Packs,
Size * Quantity / 1000 AS Rolling12Litres,
(PMDelSpl.Method) as Method,
(PMDelSpl.Size) as Size,
(PMDelSpl.Shape) as Shape,
(PMDelSpl.System) as System,
(PMDelSpl.Type) as Type,
(PMDelSpl.Category) as Category,
(PMDelSpl.SubCat) as SubCat,
 L_ProductType AS LocalCategory,
 L_ProductCategory AS LocalSubcategory,
(PMDelSpl.Place) as Place,
PMDelSpl.Group,
PMDelSpl.Distribution,
datepart( month, dateadd( month,  $(i), convert( datetime, str( PMYear ) + '/' + STR( PMMonth ) + '/01' ) ) ) as Month,
datepart( year, dateadd( month, $(i), convert( datetime, str( PMYear ) + '/' + STR( PMMonth ) + '/01' ) ) ) as Year,
dateadd( month, $(i), convert( datetime, str( PMYear ) + '/' + STR( PMMonth ) + '/01' ) ) as Period
 FROM PMDelSpl
 WHERE dateadd( month,  $(i), convert( datetime, str( PMYear ) + '/' + STR( PMMonth ) + '/01' ) ) <GETDATE();

**Next i**
```